# Write Simple Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Post
(
    postID - PK
    memberID
    title
    thread
    .
    .
    .
    reported             int DEFAULT 0,
    dateCreated          datetime DEFAULT GetDate() NOT NULL
);
```

I want to write a stored procedure that would raise "reported" field by 1 every-time i execute the procedure. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateReported(@PostID INT)
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE dbo.Post
   SET Reported = Reported + 1
   WHERE PostID = @PostID
END
```

You can then call that stored proc with:

```
EXEC dbo.UpdateReported @PostID = 5
```

or pass whatever `PostID` you want to update...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Post SET reported = (reported + 1)
```

Comment: @HLGEM, by reading the OP question I had the impression that this is what he is after: `I want to write a stored procedure that would raise "reported" field by 1`. He doesn't mention anything about raising the reported field by 1 for a particular record or am I missing something?